# Phototube experiment with op amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor, photosensor

I'm working on an experiment to find Planck's constant with a phototube. I built the following circuit and pointed an LED light to the phototube in a dark room, but I had a few problems:

1. When there is no capacitor, the reading of the voltmeter was very unstable (mainly from 1V to 3V). If I'm correct, the charge should accumulate until the blocking voltage for the phototube is reached.
2. Reducing the capacitance (to 1uF and 0.1uF) again gave unstable values. Also, with small capacitance, the voltmeter reading increased significantly when I lowered the light intensity.
3. When there is no light incident, the voltage still read around 500mV without the capacitor.

What is the flaw in this circuit, and what are the causes for the above issues? The op amp I used for the voltage follower is LMC6081 and operates with single supply. I'm completely a beginner in electric circuits so I hope if you could explain me from the basics.

[image]

Comment: Where did the circuit idea come from i.e. is there a web page that indicates how to measure Planck's constant?

Comment: [Phototube and Planck's constant.](https://foothill.edu/psme/marasco/4dlabs/4dlab4.html)

Comment: Yes, I tried to make the circuit in Figure 3 (in Page 4) of this document: http://www.unm.edu/~mph/307/Planck_UNM.pdf

Comment: The pdf mentions that the photo tube acts like a capacitor. I would assume that the leakage current of the 10uF capacitor should be much much lower than the current output from the photo tube. Are you ensuring that ? "the charge should accumulate until the blocking voltage for the photo tube is reached" : Not if there is significant leakage current through the 10uF. What *type* of capacitor are you using ?

Comment: Why don’t you show optical filters and diffraction grating?

Comment: I was using an electrolytic capacitor but just figured it has a relatively large amount of leakage current. I'll have a try with a film capacitor.

Comment: The photocurrent is microamperes.  You're going to need a relatively small capacitor, with a **very** low leakage rate.  Electrolytics are **out.**

Comment: The wild voltage readings are going to be caused by the physical setup of your rig.  You're going to need a custom made PCB, shielding on everything, and you'll have to enclose the whole mess to keep temperature variations from messing things up.  And don't even **think** the word "breadboard" while working on this.

Comment: Related to JRE's answer, can we see a photograph of the setup ?

Comment: It seems you need a "charge amplifier"...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need a separate capacitor.

From the lab description you linked to:

> The  physically  separated  anode  and  cathode  behave  as  half  of  a  cylindrical  capacitor;  the incoming  light  acts  as  a  current  source  to  charge  up  this  capacitor  (C)  with  electrons.    The total  charge  (Q)  and  potential  difference  on  this  capacitor  are  governed  by  a  fundamental equation  from  electrostatics:  Q  =  CV.

The capacitor is an inherent part of the phototube.  Your task is to measure the accumulated charge between the plate and the rod of the phototube.

That will be a **very** small capacitance.  You will need an opamp with a **very** low leakage current on its input.

The charge current will be some few microamperes.  You'll need an opamp with a leakage much lower than that.

Your [LMC6081](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmc608.pdf) seems to meet that need - it has an input impedance in the teraohm range, and leakage in the picoampere range.

To make this work, you're going to need a setup designed for this kind of stuff.

I know I'm not up to it.  I have read a bit about this kind of thing (extreme high impedance measurements) and know that I don't have the skills needed.

1. At the impedances you are dealing with, a **fingerprint** on the PCB can act as a resistor and mess up your measurements.
2. Many things you would normally consider to be insulators begin to look like conductors in comparison with the impedances you are dealing with.
3. The input pins of the opamp will react to electric fields.  You will need to keep the connection to the phototube short, and shielded.
4. Look into guard rings, you're gonna need them.

[This article from Analog Devices](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/layout-for-precision-op-amps.html) goes into some detail about things you will have to consider when building your circuit.

---

There are good reasons why the commercially available lab setups for this experiment in determining Planck's constant cost [several hundred dollars.](https://sci-supply.com/plancks-constant-apparatus-european-220-240-vac-model/)

A lot goes into them.  Keep going, and I expect you'll learn all about what makes them expensive.

Comment: Yes I was using a breadboard. I've never imagined those effects to be so huge for this experiment. I've once seen a lab setup costed $800 and I was really shocked, but now I see why. That was very helpful. I'll try my best to make it work, at least now I know what went wrong!